How to keep original array in this case?
When I console.log the results I get that the original array has changed. I can't find why? I did slice().reverse() to save the original but it doesn't work. If I edit this code so it's a 1D array it works well and the original array is unchanged.
let original = [["one", 1], ["two", 2], ["three", 3], ["four", 4], ["five", 5]];
let kopija = original.slice().reverse();

for (let i=0; i<5; i++){
    while(kopija[i][1] > 1){
        kopija[i][1]--     
    }    
}
console.log("kopija" + kopija)
console.log("original" + original)


Because slice() creates a shallow copy of the array, which means it creates a new array but still references the same nested arrays. Therefore, when you modify the nested arrays in:
kopija[i][1]--

You're also modifying the corresponding nested arrays in original because they are pointing to the same objects in memory.
To fix your case, you can use a method like map() to create new arrays for each inner array. Something like this:
let original = [["one", 1], ["two", 2], ["three", 3], ["four", 4], ["five", 5]];

// Create a deep copy using map() to clone inner arrays
let kopija = original.map(arr => [...arr]).reverse();

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    while (kopija[i][1] > 1) {
        kopija[i][1]--;
    }
}

console.log("kopija: ", kopija);
console.log("original: ", original);

By doing so, the original array will remain unchanged because "kopija" contains deep copies of the nested arrays, not just references to them.

Hm that worked. Thank you. Its confusing thou. I found this also works let kopija = original.map(arr => arr.slice().reverse();
Its a little confusing why this doesnt work: let kopija = original.map(arr => arr).reverse();
Although i managed to find this :kopija =  structuredClone(original).reverse(). Do you know are there any drawbacks with this method?

@MarkoP let kopija = original.map(arr => arr.slice().reverse(); also work but as mentioned in my answer above, .slice() just create a shallow copy of the inner array, so if your array contain nested objects or arrays, it will still be shared between "kojipa" and "original" array.
let kopija = original.map(arr => arr).reverse() did not work because here the .reverse() is just applied to the array of references, not the actual inner arrays.
structuredClone() creates a deep clone of original array, so kopija created by this way will be separated entirely from original array

Yes slice() makes shallow copy but also spread (what you did [...arr]) makes a shallow copy too. So with map() i make deep copy of a shallow copy and it works. But without spread or slice() i make deep copy of a original? And that gives shallow copy. At least it behaves like that. Am i thinking i a right direction?

When you use map() with spread syntax (Like me I used [...arr]), you are indeed creating a deep copy of each inner array. This is because each inner array's elements are copied by value (including references to nested objects or arrays), resulting in a new array that is independent of the original.
If you use map() without spread or slice (map(arr => arr)), it creates a new array with references to the same inner arrays as the original (shallow copy)

Ill need to spend some more time on it. But you helped for sure. Thank you. I read that slice() and spread goes one level deep so thats why its not working on 2D arrays as expected. And this structuredClone() method is a neat thing.
